# Nodelet namespace collision warning

Tags: ros, pluginlib, roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm implementing a solution based on a collection of nodelets that run together. But for one of these nodelets, I'm getting the following warning every time I try to run it:

> Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
> Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occured with plugin factory for class nodelet_package::NodeletName. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
> at line 212 in /opt/ros/indigo/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp

At runtime, I have a node that loads all these nodelets using nodelet.load() from nodelet/loader.h

I tried to understand and compare this nodelet with the other ones I'm using but I was not able to not guess what is wrong with this specific nodelet. Could anyone give me an example of what circumstances this warning might occur and give me tips on how to investigate this warning and potentially solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321679/nodelet-namespace-collision-warning/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2019-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @gvdhoorn, your comment gave me good insights.

In my specific case, I defined the same nodelet source file as a library multiple times on my CMakeLists.txt file:

> set (LIB_SOURCES
> .... # some cpp files
> src/PositionNodelet.cpp )
>
> add_library(PositionNodelet src/PositionNodelet.cpp)
>
> target_link_libraries(PositionNodelet ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

Then, I've removed  "src/PositionNodelet.cpp" from the  "set (LIB_SOURCES ...)" command and now it works fine.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Could anyone give me an example of what circumstances this warning might occur

the warning message mentions one such situation: a node that uses `nodelet.load(..)` but also `target_link_libraries(..)` against the libraries that host the nodelets. If you have `find_package(catkin .. COMPONENTS nodeletlib0 nodeletlib1 ..)` and finally a `target_link_libraries(.. ${catkin_LIBRARIES})` that would cause this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1